# Uses of derivatives in Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

All introductory books on calculus talk a lot about how to get derivatives of functions, this is fine with me. What however that's still confusing to me is the real use of derivatives.
for example the `y(x) = x^2` has `2x` has its derivative.
How is `2x` useful in relation to the original function.

Comment: Derivatives measure how fast a function is changing at that point. I think examples from physics convey this well. If you have an object in free fall, at time $ t $, it's fallen $ \frac{1}{2}gt^2 $ meters. Taking the derivative gets you $ gt $, and that's how fast your object is falling at time $ t $.

Comment: It tells you at rate instantaneous change occurs.  Toss a rock of a 1000 meter cliff, it's position after t seconds is 1000- 4.8t^2 meters.  It's derivative is -9.8t meters per second.  So after 2 seconds the rock will at 980.4 meters high and falling at 18.6 meters per second.

Comment: It can be as simple as this: if I know your starting and ending position, and you tell me how long it took you to get there, I can tell you your average speed during that time.. In math talk, this is because the derivative of your speed ($ct$) is constant ($c$) (we're assuming you're not changing speeds.This is a simple application of calculus.

Comment: @ElliotG I somewhat understand what derivative means, what is it used for in calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Note first that pure mathematics is silent on the **real-world application** of their concepts. And pure math is not obliged to propose any real-world application to anybody. I recall that there is an anecdote about Richard Feynman. Young Feynman was not sure about whether to study math or physics. After being asked about how useful mathematics is, the mathematics professor Feynman consulted told him something like "if you need to know how useful mathematics is in order to study math, then you are probably not suitable for pursuing an academic career in math". The point here is not about who is suitable for studying what; the point is about the math professor really told a truth about a very characteristic of math!

The problem of finding derivatives may date back to the problem of finding the slope of the tangent line to a given curve at a given point. Now if the curve is the graph of the function that gives us a position of an object at any given time, then, given any time, the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the function at the given time is interpreted as the velocity of the object at the given time. Here the mathematical objects such as functions or derivatives are employed as a **model**. In fact, you have already accepted the concept of using mathematical objects as a model for studying the real-world phenomena, i.e. the use of analytic geometry in physics. For instance, have not you seen in your mind that the graph of the function in the above example lies on a two-dimensional plane with the Cartesian coordinate axes on it? If you accepted the use of analytic geometry without a problem, then in the same token you can accept the use of derivatives. As it seems to me, it is just that you were somehow scared by the concept of derivatives so that you stopped and saw if you can find some applications of that concept to make it more real to you. If this is the case, please do not continue; make the concept more real to you by playing with it and trying to make the concept of limit, which is more fundamental than that of derivatives, more real to you first.

Comment: But, I don't think any pure mathematician would be satisfied not knowing that the derivative is the instantaneous rate of change. Not knowing this would be a severe gap in anyone's understanding of calculus.

Comment: @littleO, I guess it must be my words giving you such an impression. I was trying to accentuate the thing that don't try to understand math majorly by real-world correspondences, which is not the point. From this it cannot be inferred that one **cannot** employ some real-world phenomena to help himself understand the concepts, you know. Take it this way. If you met some math learner saying "I cannot accept imaginary numbers because I don't see a real-world correspondence in my mind", what would you say to him? You probably would say something like I said above to him.

Comment: @littleO, This need not be a perfect example. But I would say the real-world correspondences, if you are lucky to have one, are scaffolds at most. A scaffold is to be "disposed" when the building is done. Having a scaffold does nothing wrong; confusing or depending on the scaffold would lead one astray in pure math.

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives are useful for describing the ways that functions evolve. Some examples of uses are listed below;

- Can provide information to generate a tangent to a graph in the x-y plane
- Can be used to compare the effects of different variables on a function
- Find stationary points of a function e.g maxima, minima, saddle points. These allow for the values that optimise functions to be found, e.g maximising the size of a rectangle that can be drawn within an ellipse
- Show the vector of greatest increase in a scalar field, if for example you wanted to walk up the steepest part of a hill

There are many other uses of derivatives, but fundamentally, it can be very useful to understand how a function is changing under specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f'(t)$ is the instantaneous rate of change of $f$ at $t$. For example, if $f(t)$ is the distance a car has traveled along a road at time $t$, then $f'(t)$ is the car's velocity at time $t$. (And you can find out the value of $f'(t)$ by looking at the speedometer.)

The average rate of change of $f$ over the interval $[t,t+\Delta t]$ is
$$
\text{average rate of change} = \frac{f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)}{\Delta t}.
$$
Take the limit of this average rate of change as $\Delta t$ approaches $0$ to obtain the instantaneous rate of change of $f$ at time $t$:
$$
\text{instantaneous rate of change} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{f(t+\Delta t)-
f(t)}{\Delta t}.
$$